# Initializing object to handle null query results

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object model like this:

```
public class MyObject{
  public int Prop1{get;set;}
  public int Prop2{get;set;}
}
```

I use this object in a linq to sql query like this:

```
var MyQuery = from....
              where....
              select new MyObject()
                {
                  Prop1 = ...
                  Prop2 = ...
                };
```

The problem is that sometimes Prop1 turns out empty in the query and I get an error because Prop1 is null.

I'm adding this to the class:

```
public class MyObject{
...
public void Init()
{
  this.Prop1 = 0;
  this.Prop2 = 0;
}
```

How do I link Init to the event "object just got created"?

And, is solving the problem of a null by initializing the object to 0 the best way to do it anyway?

Thanks for your suggestions.

edit: I'm using Prop1 in the UI and I can't display null, must be 0.

Comment: `Prop1 = ... ?? 0` would seem easier...

Comment: Without knowing the details of what MyObject does, and what the intent of each property is, there can't really be a solid answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this way:

```
select new MyObject()
            {
              Prop1 = prop1 ?? 0;
              Prop2 = prop2 ?? 0;
            };
```

But it is better to use nullables.

Comment: 'better' depends on the processing that follows if subsequent processing would treat a null in the same way that it would treat 0, then it may make sense to convert straight away, rather than having potentially many future null checks.  As @Ocelot20 said in the comments above, it depends a lot on what `MyObject` does and how it's used.

Comment: @forsvarir Surely it depends on how it is used subsequently. I just thought from an aesthetic point of view - a LINQ query must be as clear as possible.

Comment: How can I initialize the object to 0 instead of working the initialization at the query level? What about an event handler?

Comment: @frenchie The initialization does not matter because you create the object from the results of the query. At the moment of the object creation you should assign valid values to the object properties. Since the properties are not allowed to be nulls, the only place  to eliminate nulls is in the query when the object is created. I don't see how some event handler could help.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `Nullable<int>` then?

```
public class MyObject{
  public int? Prop1{get;set;}
  public int? Prop2{get;set;}
}
```

`int?` is a shorthand of `Nullable<int>`.  That means, now `Prop1` and `Prop2` both can be `null`.

Or if you want zero, instead of null, then do this in the LINQ :

```
select new MyObject() { Prop1  = p1 ?? 0,  Prop2 = p2 ?? 0 }
```

Comment: ok, but how about creating an event handler that automatically sets the value to 0? Prop1 is used in the UI and I can't display null.

Comment: @frenshie: See the edit. BTW, you're displaying it in WPF/Silverlight application, then even with `Nullable` you can work. All you need to write a convertor which you can use in other situations as well.

Answer (score 2):

Is your database type nullable?

If so, you will need to define in your class:

```
public int? Prop1 { get; set; }
```

or convert your database type to an `int` using `Convert.ToInt32(databseField)` in your cast.

Comment: I'm using Prop1 in the UI and I can't display null; must be initialized. What do you think of the event handler?

Comment: In that case, use "Prop1= DatabaseField.Getvalueordefault()" OR "Prop1=(DatabaseField ?? "")"

Comment: No, I'm using MyObject to populate a linq query, I want to keep query-related code separate from class definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Two places you could fix:

```
 public int? Prop1{get;set;}
```

or

```
 select new MyObject()
            {
              Prop1 = // check for null here and put default value.
```

Comment: I'm using Prop1 in the UI and I can't display null; must be initialized. What do you think of the event handler?

Comment: Yes you could check in the event handler or use the 2nd option.