# creating an event handler on object initialization

Tags: c#

I have an object model like this:

```
public class MyObject{

  public int Prop1{get;set;}
  public int Prop2{get;set;}

  public void MyObjectInit()
  {
    this.Prop1 = 0;
    this.Prop2 = 0;
  }

}
```

How do I create an event handler for MyObject that triggers when the object is initialized and runs MyObjectInit.

Thanks

Comment: So, maybe off topic slightly, but I'm curious why you need an event handler to perform extra initialization. Why not just use the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use an event handler.  Just use the object constructor.

```
public void MyObject()
{
   MyObjectInit();
}
```

Or better yet, move the code of `MyObjectInit` into the constructor.

Comment: It seems this question is related to @frenchie other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164875/initializing-object-to-handle-null-query-results - still, this is the way to go. Initialize member data in the constructor.

Comment: Can you show in code how to move the object initialization into the constructor? Thanks.

Comment: In your case it's kind of redundant anyway. The default value for an `int` is already zero as it's a value type and can't be made null.

Comment: frenchie, rename your public void MyObjectInit() method name to public MyObject() and it's done.