# handling a null in linq to sql query

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object like this:

```
public class MyObject{

  public int Prop1 {get;set;}
}
```

I'm doing a linq to sql query that returns a list of MyObject like this:

```
var TheQuery = from ....
               where ....
               select new MyObject()
               {

                 Prop1 = (...... ).Sum( d => d)

               }.ToList();
```

The problem is that Prop1 is a sum of a subquery and sometimes there might be nothing returned and the Sum is null, which can't be assigned to Prop1 because it's an int.

What's a good way around this.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You already asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164875/initializing-object-to-handle-null-query-results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using a range variable:

```
var TheQuery = from ....
               where ....
               let subquery = (...... )
               select new MyObject()
               {

                 Prop1 = subquery!=null ? (subquery.Sum( d => d) ?? 0) : 0;

               }.ToList();
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think frenchie is saying that Sum returns null, not that the subquery he runs Sum on is null.

Comment: @juharr: according to msdn `Sum()` should always return a value, 0 for an empty collection.

Comment: Yes, the sum returns null; the sub query could still have elements in it

Comment: well then indeed this question is a duplicate, you should just use `Prop1 = subquery.Sum( d => d) ?? 0` - what did you not like about the previous answer? Also this means you are not using the Standard Linq Sum method, what are you using?

Comment: @BrokenGlass but what if this is linq-to-sql it would translate into a SQL Sum that would return null if all the values in the sum are null.

Comment: Yes, the sum can return null; the sub query could still have elements in it. There's also a case where the sub query could return null. Both cases exists. For now, it's actually bugging on the case where the sub query is null.

Comment: @frenchie sounds like you need `Prop1 = subquery == null ? 0 : (subquery.Sum(d=>d) ?? 0)`

Comment: @juharr: you are correct, I didn't consider linq to SQL - a combination should work in this case, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply promote your property to an `int?`. You have the sum of nothing, it's best to represent that as a null. The rationale is that it should be possible to have an *actual sum* that is 0. In this case, you do not have a sum of actual values, so keeping the null result allows you to preserve this difference.

Otherwise, you might consider (assuming the query returns the value as a nullable) invoking `.GetValueOrDefault()` on the result, which would normalize a null value to 0 in the case of a numeric type.