# How to write below sql query in linq c# where some of paramteres will be null sometimes

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I have following query in sql,

```
select * from dbo.WaitingLists 
where WaitingListTypeId in (1)
or StakeBuyInId in (Select StakeBuyInId from dbo.WaitingLists where StakeBuyInId in (5) and 
WaitingListTypeId = 2)
```

in this, sometimes StakeBuyInId will be null or WaitingListTypeId will ne null. I want to perform this query via linq c# in following code.

```
 public GameListItem[] GetMyWaitingList(Guid UserId, int LocalWaitingListTypeId, int GlobalWaitingListTypeId, int[] StakeBuyInIds)
            {
                ProviderDB db = new ProviderDB();

                List<GameListItem> objtempGameListItem = new List<GameListItem>();

                List<GameTables> objGameTablesList = new List<GameTables>();

                var objWaitingListUser = db.WaitingLists.Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(UserId));

                if (LocalWaitingListTypeId > 0 || (GlobalWaitingListTypeId > 0 && StakeBuyInIds != null))
                {
                    objWaitingListUser = objWaitingListUser.Where(x => x.WaitingListTypeId == LocalWaitingListTypeId || (x.WaitingListTypeId == GlobalWaitingListTypeId 
                                            && StakeBuyInIds != null ? StakeBuyInIds.Contains((Int32)x.StakeBuyInId) : true)
                                         );
                }
                return objtempGameListItem.ToArray();
            }
```

Here StakeBuyInIds int[] will be sometimes null, then how will i perform linq operation for above sql query. Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165750/handling-a-null-in-linq-to-sql-query?rq=1

Comment: But i want data for LocalWaitingListTypeId if that Id is greater than 0 and not want to execute that or condition linq query if StakeBuyInIds is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably just check for null outside of your expression, like this:

```
if (LocalWaitingListTypeId > 0 || (GlobalWaitingListTypeId > 0 && StakeBuyInIds != null))
{
    if (StakeBuyInIds != null)
    {
        objWaitingListUser = objWaitingListUser.Where(
            x => x.WaitingListTypeId == LocalWaitingListTypeId || 
                 (x.WaitingListTypeId == GlobalWaitingListTypeId && 
                  StakeBuyInIds.Contains((Int32)x.StakeBuyInId));
    } else {
        objWaitingListUser = objWaitingListUser.Where(
            x => x.WaitingListTypeId == LocalWaitingListTypeId || 
                 x.WaitingListTypeId == GlobalWaitingListTypeId);
    }
}
```

You might also be able to do this:

```
if (LocalWaitingListTypeId > 0 || (GlobalWaitingListTypeId > 0 && StakeBuyInIds != null))
{
    var arrayNull = StakeBuyInIds != null;
    var array = StakeBuyInIds ?? new int[0];
    objWaitingListUser = objWaitingListUser.Where(
        x => x.WaitingListTypeId == LocalWaitingListTypeId || 
             (x.WaitingListTypeId == GlobalWaitingListTypeId && 
              (arrayNotNull || array.Contains((Int32)x.StakeBuyInId)));
}
```

It effect it tests for null outside of the query, but ensures that it cannot be null when actually executing the query.

Comment: Is there any another solution using 'let' or something related to it? Because i want to optimize my code.

Comment: @KomalJariwala Well, there's nothing inefficient about this code. I suppose it's a bit more verbose than your testing for null inside the query. The problem (I think) is that you there's no direct translation of testing an array == null to SQL, so one way or other you can't actually do that inside the query expression. See my updated answer for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `waitingListTypeId` and `stakeBuyinId` should be `nullable int` in your relational object `WaitingList`.

```
List<int?> WaitingListTypeIds=new List(new int?[]{1});
    var StakeBuyInIds=from w in WaitingListsCollection where new List<int?>(new int?[]{5}).Contains(w.StakeBuyInId) && w.WaitingListTypeId = 2;
        var output= from w in WaitingListsCollection where  WaitingListTypeIds.Contains(w.WaitingListTypeId) || StakeBuyInIds.Contains(w.StakebuyInId)
```